# Switch between two pages with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a page with 2 buttons and 2 divs which are hidden.
When you click the first button the first div should appear, and if you click the second button the second div should appear.

I've managed to get that to work, but what I can't get to work is, that if I have the first div open, and click the second button, I would like it to show the second div and close the first div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.hh').click(function() {
        $(".hh_facebook").toggleClass("vis");
        $(".hg_facebook").toggleClass("skjul");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.hg').click(function() {
        $(".hg_facebook").toggleClass("vis");
        $(".hh_facebook").toggleClass("skjul");
    });
});
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mWLk/4/

Best regards
Martin

Comment: May i know why you are not using hide() and show() functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your js code is a bit incorrect.

You call twice `$(document).ready(function() {` ... Is enough once time.

try this:

```
$(function(){
  $("button.hh").on("click", function(){
     $(".hh_facebook").show();
     $(".hg_facebook").hide();
  });

  $("button.hg").on("click", function(){
     $(".hh_facebook").hide();
     $(".hg_facebook").show();
  });
});
```

see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mWLk/5/

**update** if you want to hide div after clicking on same button: http://jsfiddle.net/4mWLk/8/

Use `toggle` instead of `show` (for your comment at my answer)

PS: I updated CSS because there was not neccessary.

Comment: That seems to be working thanks :)
I've just got one extra thing if it's possible.
With your code if I got the first div page open, and click the button again, nothing happens.
Would it be possible to do so that if I got either div 1 or div 2 open and click the button corresponding to that div, the div closes?

Comment: so if you click on opened div button it should close and both div1 and div2 should be hidden in mode ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it with classes so you can have more control over the effect in case you decide to change it later, you should do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mWLk/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.hh').click(function() {
            $(".hh_facebook").toggleClass("skjul vis");
            $(".hg_facebook").removeClass("vis").addClass("skjul");
    });
    $('button.hg').click(function() {
            $(".hg_facebook").toggleClass("skjul vis");
            $(".hh_facebook").removeClass("vis").addClass("skjul");
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="hh_facebook skjul">test1</div>
<div class="hg_facebook skjul">test2</div>
```

What it does is like this:

- first the divs start with `skjul` class so they are in hidden state.
- when a button is pressed, toggle both the `skjul` and `vis` classes (one is removed, the other is added)
- make sure the second div is hidden.

Comment: See my answer, second sentence.

Comment: Thank you, didn't focused on that.

Comment: I updated the code as per your second request. So you can toggle them too.